# Parse Json Rose Tree with Haskell Aeson

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I'm trying to parse recursive JSON data, something like this:

```
{
    "node": "a",
    "children": [
        {
            "node": "b",
            "children": [
                {
                    "node": "c",
                    "children": null
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "node": "d",
            "children": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to implement an instance of FromJSON, so that I can decode it into a data structure like this:
the following data structure

```
data Tree = Node { value :: Text, children :: [Tree]} | Nothing
```

I have no clue how to do this. I have only seen examples on how to derive instances for flat (non-recursive) JSON structures using Aeson.

Comment: The problem here is more the fact that you use `null` instead of an empty list. Furthermore why do you create a constructor `Nothing` here? Without the `null` case, this is actually *completely* the same as non-flat data.

Comment: You are right. It is really simple if you just use empty lists to represent no children!

Comment: So... problem solved?

Comment: @lsund It should be quite straightforward to [define custom](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-1.4.0.0/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:2) `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` instances manually. Do you need help with that? (If no, you can also answer your own question, and this is encouraged!)

Comment: I answered my own question. Thank you all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Willem von Onsem suggested, this is much simpler if you define the data like this:

`data Tree = Node { value :: Text, children :: [Tree]}`, just using an empty list for representing (also in the json) empty subtrees. Then, you just parse the json directly by just deriving `fromJSON` of the datatype.

Another idea is to use `Data.Tree` which already has a derived instance of `fromJSON`. For Data.Tree, the JSON has to be structured something like like this:

```
["a",["b",[]]]
```